# HTML Agility can't parse <span> when it changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the price of a currency pair using HTML Agility Pack, i am able to parse the price when it is first parsed but the prices changes regularly.

```
            string asset = cmbPair.Text.ToString();
            var html = @"https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/" + asset;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            web.CacheOnly = false;

            var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
            //All 3 Nodes
            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='price-section__values']").InnerText;
            //Singular Nodes
            var onlyprice = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[starts-with(@class, 'price-section__current-value')]").InnerText; //Need this when it updates
            var onlypricechange = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='price-section__absolute-value']").InnerText;
            var onlyperchange = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='price-section__relative-value']").InnerText;

            
            //htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='price-section__current-value price-section__current-value--positive-updated']").InnerText;
            //htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='price-section__current-value price-section__current-value--negative-updated']").InnerText;
```

As previously mentioned the price does infact parse but not when the price changes, I have made the function to run using the timer on Visual Studio to run every 500ms but it doesnt update the price.

I have checked the code of the website using inspect element and have noticed that the `price-section__current-value` changes to `price-section__current-value price-section__current-value--positive-updated` if price goes up and `price-section__current-value price-section__current-value--negative-updated` when price goes down. In order to try get the node to parse I used the  starts-with function which doesn't change anything.

Any help with my code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you see while inspecting the live page are probably irrelevant. When an HTTP client (`HtmlWeb` in this case) requests a page, it will get a single response and that's that. If your code works the first time, it should work the second time as well.

There may be something wrong with the way you do your subsequent requests, but your code sample doesn't include that part.

For what it's worth, here is a working sample that I have tested during the weekend:

```
var asset = "eur-usd";
string html = @"https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/" + asset;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    CacheOnly = false
};

var counter = 0;
while (++counter <= 10)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(html);

    string onlyprice = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'price-section__current-value')]").InnerText; //Need this when it updates
    string onlypricechange = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'price-section__absolute-value')]").InnerText;
    string onlyperchange = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'price-section__relative-value')]").InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine($"Attempt {counter}");
    Console.WriteLine($"price-section__current-value: {onlyprice}");
    Console.WriteLine($"price-section__absolute-value: {onlypricechange}");
    Console.WriteLine($"price-section__relative-value: {onlyperchange}");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Notice that I have changed your selectors to use the `contains` function.

If during market hours (as opposed to the weekend) the classes on the `span`s do change, depending on the price movement, then you might need to modify your XPath selectors accordingly to make them more robust.